# How to join results of stored procedures (ODBC, VBA, Quickbooks, QODBC)

Tags: sql, vba, odbc, quickbooks, qodbc

I'm trying to join the results of a stored procedure available through the QODBC driver and a table also available through the QODBC driver

Essentially I would like to do (in general terms):

```
(StoredProcedure [Fields] [parameters]) C 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Fields] FROM Table) A 
ON C.KeyID=A.KeyID
```

OR

```
SELECT [Fields] 
FROM Table A RIGHT JOIN (StoredProcedure [Fields] [parameters]) C 
ON A.KeyID=C.KeyID
```

Which I understand should give me the same result.

1 - Stored Procedure Query

```
sp_report CustomSummary show Label, RowData, LabelAccountName, 
Amount, NumColTitleRows, RowType, ReportSubtitle parameters 
DateMacro='LastYear', SummarizeRowsBy = 'Account', 
SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Month', Calendar = 'FiscalYear', 
ReturnRows = 'All', ReturnColumns = 'All', ReportBasis='Accrual', 
AccountFilterType='IncomeAndExpense'
```

2 - Query

```
SELECT Name, AccountType FROM Account
```

I tried the below variations, which did not work:

```
SELECT AccountType, * FROM (sp_report CustomSummary show Label, RowData, LabelAccountName, 
Amount, NumColTitleRows, RowType, ReportSubtitle parameters DateMacro='LastYear', 
SummarizeRowsBy = 'Account', SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Month', Calendar = 'FiscalYear', ReturnRows = 'All', 
ReturnColumns = 'All', ReportBasis='Accrual', AccountFilterType='IncomeAndExpense') C 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name, AccountType FROM Account) A ON C.LabelAccountName = A.Name
```

OR

```
SELECT Name, AccountType FROM Accounts A RIGHT JOIN (sp_report CustomSummary show 
Label, RowData, LabelAccountName, Amount, NumColTitleRows, RowType, 
ReportSubtitle parameters DateMacro='LastYear', SummarizeRowsBy = 'Account', SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Month', 
Calendar = 'FiscalYear', ReturnRows = 'All', ReturnColumns = 'All', ReportBasis='Accrual', 
AccountFilterType='IncomeAndExpense') C ON A.Name = C.LabelAccountName
```

Are there any suggestions for doing this without dumping both to temporary tables and joining?

Comment: How come you tagged everything but sql?

Comment: ran out of tags; editted

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of MS Access or Excel or temporary tables. Export data of report and tables to Excel sheets and then perform link/join.

Refer: http://qodbc.com/links/2900

> Are there any suggestions for doing this without dumping both to temporary tables and joining?

You cannot join a stored procedure and a table thus you will need to get the output sorted locally or in temporary tables.